# Acesso dinâmico coluna cursor oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, procedure, cursor

Tenho uma situação em que eu preciso acessar os atributos de um cursor de forma diferente. Tenho um cursor que me retorna uma lista de registros, com colunas como col_1, col_nova, col_teste (nomes ilustrativos).

Faço um loop nesse cursor para ajustar uma string de retorno. Mas para acessar o valor dessa coluna no cursor, eu não quero fazer como r_cursor.col_1.

Eu tenho uma tabela que armazena o valor das colunas que eu preciso trabalhar. Seguindo o exemplo das colunas citadas antes, nessa tabela tenho gravados os registros col_1 e col_nova. Agora no loop do cursor, eu não posso definir manualmente que eu vou usar os valores de uma coluna, sendo que ela pode não ser usada.

Então queria saber se existe alguma forma para realizar o loop dos registros principais. Para cada um desses registros, acesso a lista de colunas que são acessadas por um laço em outro cursor, que ficam armazenados como registros em outra tabela. E com a informação da coluna do segundo cursor, pegar o valor da coluna de mesmo nome do primeiro cursor?

Uma exemplificação lógica do que seria

```
cursor_1 = select * na tabela principal;
cursor_2 = lista de colunas utilizadas. Que vai retornar a lista em um atributo chamado COLUNA;

    loop cursor_1
      loop cursor_2
        v_armazenar := v_armazenar || ' COLUNA '||cursor_2.COLUNA || ' VALOR: '||??????;
      end cursor_2
    end cursor_1
```

Onde em ?????? eu mostraria o valor dessa coluna vinda do cursor_1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bolei um pequeno exemplo aqui que deve clarear as ideias ae.

```
DECLARE VSQL VARCHAR2(4000);
VARMAZNAR VARCHAR2(4000);
VTEMP VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

--SELECT PRINCIPAL
FOR PRINCIPAL IN (SELECT * FROM PCCLIENT WHERE CODCLI < 10)
LOOP



--TABELA COM AS COLUNAS
FOR COLUNAS IN(SELECT 'CODCLI' COLUNA FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 'CLIENTE' COLUNA FROM DUAL)
LOOP

--STRING SQL PRA EXECUTAR
VSQL := 'SELECT  '||COLUNAS.COLUNA|| ' FROM PCCLIENT WHERE CODCLI = '||PRINCIPAL.CODCLI;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VSQL INTO VTEMP;
--GUARDA O RESULTADO EM ALGUM LUGAR
VARMAZNAR:= VARMAZNAR|| 'COLUNA: ' ||COLUNAS.COLUNA || ' VALOR: ' ||VTEMP || '| ';


END LOOP;

END LOOP;
--EXIBE O RESULTADO
dbms_output.put_line(VARMAZNAR);



END;
```

O resultado:

```
COLUNA: CLIENTE VALOR: CONSUMIDOR FINAL| COLUNA: CODCLI VALOR: 1|
```

Comment: Funcionou. @jeterson-miranda-gomes, sabe se seria possível, ao invés de eu usar o PRINCIPAL.CODCLI, no lugar do CODCLI, usar a COLUNAS.COLUNA. Algo como PRINCIPAL.[COLUNAS.COLUNA]? Para caso eu queira deixar mais dinâmico ainda. Obrigado pela ajuda.